# ¿Cómo insertar datos en orden específico desde consulta o arreglo PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un formulario de contacto el cual funciona correctamente en el se almacena:

[image: tabla donde muestro los datos]

y el asesor lo asigno de esta manera:

[image: listado de asesores que están en la bd, en una tabla distinta]

la idea es que desde la inserción en el formulario se asigne automáticamente un asesor, y al terminar la lista de asesores vuelva nuevamente al inicio para continuar asignando un asesor a cada contacto. 
la verdad le he dado muchas vueltas pero no he logrado nada aun.

```
<?php 

$servidor='localhost';
$usuario='usuario';
$pass='';
$bd='base de datos';


$conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $pass, $bd);  
$conexion->set_charset('utf8');

if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
  echo "Error al conectar la base de datos {$conexion->connect_errno}";
}

$fecha_registro=date("Y-m-d");  
$nombre_con=isset($_POST['nombre_con'])? $_POST['nombre_con'] : NULL;
        $telefono=isset($_POST['telefono'])? $_POST['telefono'] : NULL;;
        $correo=isset($_POST['correo'])? $_POST['correo'] : NULL;;

        $id_usuario=isset($_POST['id_usuario'])? next($_POST['id_usuario']) : NULL;;


        $mensaje=isset($_POST['mensaje'])? $_POST['mensaje'] : NULL;;
        $fecha_con=$fecha_registro;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
       // $query="INSERT INTO contactos  
VALUES('$nombre','$telefono','$correo','$mensaje')";

$query="INSERT INTO contactos (nombre_con, telefono, correo, id_usuario, mensaje,fecha_con) VALUES ('".$nombre_con."','".$telefono."', '".$correo."','".$id_usuario."', '".$mensaje."', '".$fecha_con."')" or die(mysql_error());


 if ($conexion->query($query))
    {


   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
       myFn();


      </script>';

    }

    else
    {
        echo "El evento no se pudo eliminar";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: No soy muy bueno en `PHP` pero en lo que he investigado y he puesto en practica te puedo sugerir el uso de un ciclo `while` o el de un `for` para que asi cuando se asigne un asesor y este termine se regrese a su punto de incio.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas que todos tus asesores tengan el mismo numero de usuarios, puedes ir agregando nuevos usuarios al asesor que tenga menos usuarios, vía sql seria mas o menos así:

```
SELECT asesor FROM contactos GROUP BY asesor ORDER BY count(*) as num_usuarios ASC LIMIT 1
```